# Quickblox Android web-rtc -- onRemoteVideoTrackReceive not called

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox

I'm prototyping a QuickBlox Video client on Android. To test it out I just have the code to **receive** calls at the moment and am using the JavaScript test client (with hardwired users in my account) to **generate** the call. My code is based on the QuickBlox Android tutorial (for the 'new' web-rtc app).

Essentially all seems to go well (see log below) for a while. The call goes through to the tablet and  it calls **acceptCall** (with an empty map as argument). **onLocalVideoTrackReceive** gets called which turns on the tablet's camera (and the local view appears in the UI). However even though `acceptCall` has been called the client keeps ringing and the **callback `onRemoteVideoTrackReceived` is never called**.

The tablet app does not crash. I happily logs the fact it is using its camera but nothing else happens. Eventually, I manually hang up the client.

```
    18:35:26.770  15909-16114/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ =========================================================
        === REQUEST ==== 5e751fe9-4186-445a-9ebc-9008143860c6 ===
        REQUEST
        POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
        HEADERS
        QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
        QB-SDK=Android 2.2.6
        PARAMETERS
        application_id=25788
        auth_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX
        nonce=-1153424146
        timestamp=1437528926
        user[login]=YYYYYYYYYYYYY
        user[password]=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
        signature=WWWWWWWWWWWWW
        INLINE
        POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=25788&auth_key=xcA5Xc2R53Cgrz3&nonce=-1153424146×tamp=1437528926&user[login]=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&user[password]=YYYYYYYYYYY&
    signature=WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW

    18:35:27.296  15909-16114/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ *********************************************************
        *** RESPONSE *** 5e751fe9-4186-445a-9ebc-9008143860c6 ***
        STATUS : 201
        HEADERS
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
        Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
        Connection=keep-alive
        Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
        Date=Wed, 22 Jul 2015 01:35:27 GMT
        ETag="381f79ac0b50dfd6332d658570ed1c61"
        QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2015-07-22 03:35:27 UTC
        QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
        Server=nginx/1.0.15
        Status=201 Created
        Transfer-Encoding=chunked
        X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
        X-Request-Id=a1a2781b1ab340fd1e462e200e627770
        X-Runtime=0.026241
        X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
        BODY
        '{"session":{"_id":"55aef35f535c126116002461","application_id":XXXXXX,"created_at":"2015-07-22T01:35:27Z","device_id":0,"nonce":-1153424146,"token":"d5678a7685eec907f6226591e4031cf569a7a973","ts":1437528926,"updated_at":"2015-07-22T01:35:27Z","user_id":4268341,"id":5595}}'
    18:35:27.369  15909-16114/com.coms D/QuickBloxService﹕ got session QBSession{token='d5678a7685eec907f6226591e4031cf569a7a973', appId=25788, userId=4268341, deviceId=0, timestamp=1437528926, nonce=-1153424146}

    18:35:28.388  15909-16114/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Create INSTANCE
    18:35:28.389  15909-16114/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Init client tasks EXECUTOR
    18:35:28.389  15909-16114/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper start. On QBRTCClient
    18:35:28.404  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Looper thread started.
    18:35:28.425  15909-16114/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ ADD CALLBACK com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e
    18:35:28.426  15909-16114/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ ADD CALLBACK com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e
    18:35:28.426  15909-16114/com.coms E/MsgProcessor﹕ Try to add  null SmackSignallingProcessorCallback listener
    18:35:28.431  15909-16183/com.coms D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): 
    18:35:28.464  15909-15924/com.coms I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32529(2033KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(151KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 14MB/16MB, paused 5.004ms total 85.510ms
    18:36:28.318  15909-16182/com.coms D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): 
    18:36:28.411  15909-16183/com.coms D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): 
    18:36:32.353  15909-16183/com.coms D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): WebRTCVideoChatcall14375289842651v=0
        o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-39.0 4294967295 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
        s=-
        t=0 0
        a=sendrecv
        a=fingerprint:sha-256 C0:E6:07:F1:15:72:CC:24:93:7D:D9:DA:D2:7D:A4:42:7E:41:F2:6E:9F:9A:7B:98:49:A7:06:EE:70:AC:4D:2E
        a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0 sdparta_1
        a=ice-options:trickle
        a=msid-semantic:WMS *
        m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
        c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
        a=sendrecv
        a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
        a=ice-pwd:1206bfba48e268d7e5d6af337cf5da23
        a=ice-ufrag:e0be8eb3
        a=mid:sdparta_0
        a=msid:{1947eb01-41ad-4ce1-8481-82b006a3c7ef} {6f381987-02b3-44ef-a43d-5e347bbfc247}
        a=rtcp-mux
        a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
        a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
        a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
        a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
        a=setup:actpass
        a=ssrc:1080179391 cname:{917d1c3d-afc8-4168-8dbf-e2d3ac9144f0}
        m=video 9 RTP/SAVPF 120 126 97
        c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
        a=sendrecv
        a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
        a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
        a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
        a=ice-pwd:1206bfba48e268d7e5d6af337cf5da23
        a=ice-ufrag:e0be8eb3
        a=mid:sdparta_1
        a=msid:{1947eb01-41ad-4ce1-8481-82b006a3c7ef} {9d584e62-e48e-4ce2-bd98-77b0c1863383}
        a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
        a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
        a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
        a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
        a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
        a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
        a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
        a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
        a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
        a=rtcp-mux
        a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
        a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
        a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
        a=setup:actpass
        a=ssrc:2574623186 cname:{917d1c3d-afc8-4168-8dbf-e2d3ac9144f0}
        web43084764268341
    18:36:32.355  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Start cycle
    18:36:32.355  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Tag type is: 2,name is opponentID
    18:36:32.355  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Tag type is: 4, value is 4268341
    18:36:32.355  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Tag type is: 3,name is opponentID
    18:36:32.355  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Finish cycle
    18:36:32.356  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parser -->>﹕ Tag is 4268341
    18:36:32.356  15909-16183/com.coms D/Parsed message﹕ opponentsIDs  -->  4268341
    18:36:32.379  15909-16188/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ New signalling was added
    18:36:32.422  15909-16188/com.coms E/QuickBloxService﹕ Added Signaling com.quickblox.chat.QBWebRTCSignaling@23080481
    18:36:32.425  15909-16188/com.coms D/QBRTCSessionDescription﹕ Was created QBRTCSessionDescription{sessionID='1437528984265', callerID='4308476', opponents=[4268341], conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='1'}, userInfo={}}
    18:36:32.426  15909-16188/com.coms D/MsgProcessor﹕ notify income call
    18:36:32.431  15909-16188/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:36:32.431  15909-16188/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1250
    18:36:32.434  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Call offer message received
    18:36:32.435  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ createSessionWithDescription
    18:36:32.451  15909-16198/com.coms D/EglBase﹕ SDK version: 22
    18:36:32.453  15909-16198/com.coms D/*WEBRTCN*﹕ SetRenderAndroidVM
    18:36:32.453  15909-16198/com.coms D/JVM﹕ JVM::Initialize@[tid=16198]
    18:36:32.453  15909-16198/com.coms D/JVM﹕ JVM::JVM@[tid=16198]
    18:36:32.454  15909-16198/com.coms D/MediaCodecVideo﹕ SetAndroidObjects for surface decoding.
    18:36:32.454  15909-16198/com.coms D/MediaCodecVideo﹕ NULL VideoDecoder EGL context - HW surface decoding is disabled.
    18:36:32.476  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::ctor@[tid=17205]
    18:36:32.476  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ Attaching thread to JVM
    18:36:32.476  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ JVM::environment@[tid=17205]
    .... Lots of audio and video setup

    18:36:32.486  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioManager﹕ Init@[tid=17205]
    18:36:32.486  15909-17205/com.coms D/WebRtcAudioManager﹕ init@[name=Thread-1251, id=1251]
    18:36:32.487  15909-17205/com.coms D/WebRtcAudioManager﹕ audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
    18:36:32.489  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ EnableBuiltInAEC@[tid=17205]
    18:36:32.489  15909-17205/com.coms D/WebRtcAudioRecord﹕ EnableBuiltInAEC(true)
    18:36:32.494  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ EnableBuiltInAEC@[tid=17205]
    18:36:32.494  15909-17205/com.coms D/WebRtcAudioRecord﹕ EnableBuiltInAEC(true)
    18:36:32.498  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Peer connection factory initiated
    18:36:32.503  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Create looper executor on thread: 1250
    18:36:32.503  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper start. On QBPeerChannel
    18:36:32.504  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Looper thread started.
    18:36:32.505  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Make new channel:com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerChannel@188f6926
    18:36:32.505  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Notify all session calback listeners about session creation
    18:36:32.505  15909-16198/com.coms D/SessionClosedListener﹕ onReceiveNewSession
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ acceptCall
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ startAsAnswer
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers﹕ Stop WaitTimer
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1254
    18:36:32.528  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Try to set null remote sdp
    18:36:32.529  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ createConnection
    18:36:32.529  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ EXECUTE.Run on thread:1250
    18:36:32.529  15909-16198/com.coms E/QuickBloxService﹕ Accepted Incoming Call: QBRTCSession{sessionDescription=QBRTCSessionDescription{sessionID='1437528984265', callerID='4308476', opponents=[4268341], conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='1'}, userInfo={}}, getMediaStreamManager=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager@2fc617b, channels={4308476=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerChannel@188f6926}, signalChannel=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel@b4b2b98, chatCallbackList=[com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@24140113, com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e], audioEnabled=false, videoEnabled=false, state=QB_RTC_SESSION_ACTIVE, isNeedClose=false} false false
    18:36:32.535  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Process income call from 4308476
    18:36:32.535  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ set remote sdp v=0
        o=mozilla...THIS
    18:36:32.764  15909-15909/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ ADD CALLBACK com.coms.VideoActivity@265390e3
    18:36:32.768  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Local Stream Add
    18:36:32.768  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Init local media stream
    18:36:32.768  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Add video stream
    18:36:32.772  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ VideoCapturerAndroid
    18:36:32.773  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ init: Camera 1, Facing front, Orientation 270
    18:36:32.773  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Get supported formats.
    18:36:32.773  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Opening camera 1
    18:36:32.873  15909-17223/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ onSurfaceChanged
    18:36:32.886  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ onSurfaceChanged
    18:36:33.304  15909-15909/com.coms E/ComMain﹕ onStop
    18:36:33.690  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Opening camera 0
    18:36:34.056  15909-17214/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Get supported formats done.

    18:36:34.066  15909-17205/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ startCapture requested: 640x480@30
    18:36:34.072  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Opening camera 1
    18:36:34.076  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:36:34.076  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1250
    18:36:34.077  15909-16198/com.coms E/***********﹕ Got local tracker
    18:36:34.082  15909-17214/com.coms D/AppRTCAudioManager﹕ Android SDK: 22, Release: 5.1.1, Brand: google, Device: flo, Id: LMY48G, Hardware: flo, Manufacturer: asus, Model: Nexus 7, Product: razor
    18:36:34.082  15909-17214/com.coms D/AppRTCAudioManager﹕ init

    18:36:35.195  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ QBGLVideoView
    18:36:36.251  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ QBGLVideoView
    18:36:37.318  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ QBGLVideoView
    18:36:38.337  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ QBGLVideoView
    18:36:39.349  15909-17224/com.coms D/QBASDK﹕ QBGLVideoView
    18:36:39.873  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Camera fps: 11. CaptureBuffers: 3.0. Pending buffers: []

    18:37:02.457  15909-16183/com.coms D/SMACK﹕ RCV (0): manuallyWebRTCVideoChathangUp1437528984265
    18:37:02.458  15909-16188/com.coms D/MsgProcessor﹕ Wrong caller id was set
    18:37:02.459  15909-16188/com.coms D/QBRTCSessionDescription﹕ Was created QBRTCSessionDescription{sessionID='1437528984265', callerID='null', opponents=null, conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='2'}, userInfo={}}
    18:37:02.459  15909-16188/com.coms D/MsgProcessor﹕ notify stop call
    18:37:02.459  15909-16188/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.459  15909-16188/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1250
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Stop message received
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Process hang up from 4308476
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Сhannel to hang up exists. Hangup task will be add to queue
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Call procHungUp
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Method PeerCOnnection.close started
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers﹕ Stop DialingTimer
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers﹕ Stop WaitTimer
    18:37:02.462  15909-16198/com.coms D/PeerChannelLifeCycleTimers﹕ Stop DisconnectTimer
    18:37:02.463  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.463  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1254
    18:37:02.463  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper stop. On QBPeerChannel
    18:37:02.463  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify users about hangUp session in count of 2
    18:37:02.463  15909-16198/com.coms D/SessionClosedListener﹕ onReceiveHangUpFromUser
    18:37:02.464  15909-16198/com.coms E/QuickBloxService﹕ onReceiveHangUpFromUser
    18:37:02.464  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ EXECUTE.Run on thread:1250
    18:37:02.464  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Closing peer add in task queue.
    18:37:02.464  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Closing peer connection start.
    18:37:02.465  15909-17206/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.Observer:﹕ onIceConnectionChange to CLOSED
    18:37:02.465  15909-17206/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.465  15909-17206/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1254
    18:37:02.466  15909-17206/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.Observer:﹕ onIceGatheringChange to COMPLETE
    18:37:02.466  15909-17206/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.Observer:﹕ onSignalingChange to CLOSED
    18:37:02.480  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Closing peer connection done.
    18:37:02.480  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Looper thread finished.
    18:37:02.480  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ PeerChannel succesfulle stoped
    18:37:02.480  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ Call method onChannelConnectionClosed on PeerChannel callback
    18:37:02.480  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ onChannelConnectionClosed add in executor queue
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1250
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.Observer:﹕ onIceConnectionChange
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel.Observer:﹕ IceConnectionState: CLOSED
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBPeerChannel﹕ onChannelConnectionClosed called on QBRTCSession{sessionDescription=QBRTCSessionDescription{sessionID='1437528984265', callerID='4308476', opponents=[4268341], conferenceType=QBConferenceType{value='1'}, userInfo={}}, getMediaStreamManager=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBMediaStreamManager@2fc617b, channels={4308476=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerChannel@188f6926}, signalChannel=com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel@b4b2b98, chatCallbackList=[com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@24140113, com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e], audioEnabled=false, videoEnabled=false, state=QB_RTC_SESSION_ACTIVE, isNeedClose=false}
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ onChannelConnectionClosed add in executor queue
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.481  15909-17214/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ POST.Run on thread:1250
    18:37:02.482  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Srat process onChannelConnectionClosed
    18:37:02.483  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Check is session need close
    18:37:02.483  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Session isNeedToClose true
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Start session close.
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Set session 1437528984265 with state QB_RTC_SESSION_ACTIVE to CLOSE
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Closing mediaStreamManager.
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Video source start dispose
    18:37:02.484  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Video source is org.webrtc.VideoSource@3bd13fd2
    18:37:02.491  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Video source state is LIVE
    18:37:02.492  15909-17205/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ stopCapture
    18:37:02.493  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ stopCaptureOnCameraThread
    18:37:02.493  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Stop preview.
    18:37:03.055  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ stopReturnBuffersToCamera called. All buffers have been returned.
    18:37:03.055  15909-17284/com.coms D/Camera﹕ app passed NULL surface
    18:37:03.056  15909-17284/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ Release camera.
    18:37:03.057  15909-15925/com.coms W/Camera-JNI﹕ callback on dead camera object
    18:37:03.057  15909-15925/com.coms W/Camera-JNI﹕ callback on dead camera object
    18:37:03.604  15909-17205/com.coms D/VideoCapturerAndroid﹕ stopCapture done
    18:37:03.613  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Video source disposed
    18:37:03.613  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Audio manager start close
    18:37:03.613  15909-16198/com.coms D/AppRTCAudioManager﹕ closePeerConnection
    18:37:03.624  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBMediaStrMgr﹕ Audio manager closed
    18:37:03.624  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callbacks in count of:2
    18:37:03.624  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callback: com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@24140113
    18:37:03.624  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Closing peer connection factory.
    18:37:03.625  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ Terminate@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.625  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ StopPlayout@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.625  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ Terminate@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.625  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ StopRecording@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.625  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioManager﹕ Close@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/WebRtcAudioManager﹕ dispose@[name=Thread-1251, id=1251]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ ~dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ Terminate@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioRecordJni﹕ StopRecording@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ GlobalRef::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ NativeRegistration::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ JNIEnvironment::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ Terminate@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ StopPlayout@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ DestroyAudioPlayer
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ DestroyMix
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/OpenSLESPlayer﹕ DestroyEngine
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioManager﹕ ~dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioManager﹕ Close@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/AudioManager﹕ JavaAudioManager::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ GlobalRef::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ NativeRegistration::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ JNIEnvironment::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::dtor@[tid=17205]
    18:37:03.626  15909-17205/com.coms D/JVM﹕ Detaching thread from JVM
    18:37:03.640  15909-17206/com.coms W/art﹕ Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[28,tid=17206,Native,Thread*=0xa211c000,peer=0x12ea60a0,"signaling_threa - 17206"]
    18:37:03.641  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Closing session done.
    18:37:03.641  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callback: com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms E/QuickBloxService﹕ onSessionClosed
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ EXECUTE.Run on thread:1250
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Srat process onChannelConnectionClosed
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Check is session need close
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Session isNeedToClose true
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ Request Looper execute.
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Start session close.
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Closing mediaStreamManager.
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callbacks in count of:2
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callback: com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient$SessionClosedListener@24140113
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Closing peer connection factory.
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient﹕ Nothing to close factory was null
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession﹕ Notify sesions callback: com.coms.service.QuickBloxService@2039de4e
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms E/QuickBloxService﹕ onSessionClosed
    18:37:03.642  15909-16198/com.coms D/LooperExecutor﹕ EXECUTE.Run on thread:1250
```

(Chat Debug is turned on). I think things go wrong at 18:37:02.458 where the log has a 'Wrong caller id was set' and 02.459 has as QBRTCSessionDescription with a null callerID. Then MsgProcessor gives a 'notify stop call' which can't be good.

Later I hang up on the sender side as clearly nothing is happening.

It seems to me that the QB session and the Chat session are fine and RTC signalling appears to work  (if I replace the acceptCall by a rejectCall the client hangs up immediately) yet the call never fully goes through.

Documentation on QuickBlox isn't exactly great but the code I have models their sample pretty closely. If there is a clue in the log I can't fathom it. Does anyone have any thoughts ??

Tnx

Comment: I should add that running Javascript client to Javascript client the Quickblox video chat works just fine - so the changes to the demo javascript client to wire it to users in my account did not introduce any issues .. the problem definitely seems to be on the Android side

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today; after updating to the latest SDK.

You will also need to update your jniLibs from the SDK, in my case it was **libjingle_peerconnection_so**

Answer (score 0):

[Sample-webrtc-android Prepare your application for Android SDK](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK)

You may find this title in Quickblox doc : Add signalling manager

If you add so file to your project, then please check this you did.

```
    QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager().addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdlocally) 
    {
         if (!createdlocally) 
         {
         rtcClient.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: You may add some more comments to explain why this solves the question.

Comment: https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK

Comment: https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK

You may find this title in above link : 
Add signalling manager